# Adding overlay image over grid item on item select

Tags: android, gridview, overlay, selector

What I want to do is to add a half-transparent image on selected item. I am trying to simulate the same effect that iphone adds its buttons on tap event. I have a gridview containing different images in each item. When I use a selector to make this effect only background of the images are affected not the images themselves.

Google Play Application does this. When an item is tapped it sets a blue overlay on the selected item.

How can I do this?